# Viewmodelprovider context type missmatch

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-room

i'm trying to make simple to do app with room data base with mvvm when i try to provider the view model in the list fragment always getting an error for the miss type of the view model provider because he wants a view model store owner type and i'm giving him a THIS of the fragment and i have implementation every thing of model and tried every thing to fix it and still g

---

```
class listfragment : Fragment() {
// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private var param1: String? = null
private var param2: String? = null


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    arguments?.let {
        param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
        param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
    }
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val xml= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listfragment, container, false)
    val list=ArrayList<shopinglist>()
    viewmodel= ViewModelProvider(this).get(Listviewmodel::class.java)
                         error is here 


    xml.recyclerView.layoutManager= LinearLayoutManager(context, RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false)
        xml.recyclerView.adapter=Customadapterforrecyle(this,list)

    xml.btnlist.setOnClickListener {
```

> Blockquote

```
    }
return xml
}
```

}

```
class Listviewmodel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {
  lateinit var  readallitem : LiveData<List<shopinglist>>
  lateinit var Reposotory:repository
  init {
      val dao=database.getdatabase(application).getlistgdao()
       Reposotory=repository(dao)
       readallitem=Reposotory.getallitem()
  }
    fun insert(item:shopinglist)=CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        Reposotory.insert(item)
    }
    fun delete(item:shopinglist)=CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        Reposotory.delete(item)
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: check below ...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to use the `by viewModels` property delegate?
Something like this

```
private val viewModel: HomeViewModel by viewModels {
    HomeViewModelFactory(AppDatabase.getInstance(requireActivity().application).databaseDao)
}
```

If you pass arguments to the viewModel you should have a ViewModelFactory as I have (I pass down the Database Dao to the VM). Otherwise it should be really simple to use the property delegate.

Here's an example of my ViewModelFactory class

```
class HomeViewModelFactory(private val dataSource: DatabaseDao) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
   override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(HomeViewModel::class.java))
            return HomeViewModel(dataSource) as T
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
   }
}
```